# How to replace data attributes (data-*)in CSS3 so that they work in CSS2.1

Tags: html, css, custom-data-attribute

I have the following CSS3 code:

```
[data-class=float1]
    {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 0.1rem 0;
    }
```

Now i want to make my page work in IE7/IE8, and as they dont support css3, i need to find alternative for this code in CSS2.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is no CSS2.1 equivalent for `rem` in CSS3 so you're going to have a bit of trouble with that. But if you're referring to data attributes, CSS2.1 supports them just fine since attribute selectors were introduced in CSS2.1. There are new attribute selectors in CSS3, but the one you're using is not new.

Comment: Thanks for this information. One more thing, as these attributes are of part HTML5 so will they be supported in IE7/IE8. If not then whats the alternative?

Comment: @Jash: They should be supported. If not, the only alternative is to add a concrete `class` instead of using data attributes.

Comment: Selectors like `[data-class=float1]` work just fine in IE 7, provided that it’s in Standards Mode (but then again, even IE 9 does not support them in Quirks Mode). You can even use your own attribute names and selectors like `[foo=bar]`, because CSS support in browsers does not care of what’s allowed *in HTML* in different versions.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is the `rem` unit, which has [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem) (no support in IE 8 or earlier). In most cases, it can easily be replaced by the use of the `em` unit, just paying attention to possible effects of font size settings for nested elements. Just remember that the `em` unit equals the font size of the current element.